# Customizing rails error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I have problem with custom messages for validators in rails4. I have app with devise registration system. I have some validators in my model:

```
 validates :name, length: {maximum: 45}, presence: true
 validates :surname, length: {maximum: 45}, presence: true
 validates :phone, :phony_plausible => true, presence: true
 validates :company_name, length: {maximum: 100}, presence: true
 validates :address, length: {maximum: 50}, presence: true
 validates :city, length: {maximum: 70}, presence: true
 validates :zip_code, presence: true, length: {is: 6}
 validates :nip, nip: true
```

When user left blank input for name there's a message:

```
Name can't be blank
```

When I add a message options to my validator:

```
  validates :name, length: {maximum: 45}, presence: {message: "Imię nie może być puste"}
```

I have the following message: Name Imię nie może być puste.
I don't want to have this Name word in my message. How to do this?

Comment: Which rails form are you using `Form_for` or `Simple_form`?

Comment: im using default form_for

Answer (score 0):

In your config/locales/en.yml

`en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      [model_name_goes_here]:
        [attribute_name_goes here]: ""
    errors:
      models:
        [model_name_goes_here]:
          attributes:
            [attribute_name_goes_here]:
              blank: "Email can't be blank"`

Example:

`en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        email: "" 
    errors:
      models:
        veteran:
          attributes:
            email:
              blank: "Email can't be blank"`

For example, instead of displaying "Email can't be blank" it would display 
"can't be blank". Essentialy you are replacing the "name:" with an alias that is equal to an empty string. You can set "name:" to name: "Your name"

`en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        name: "Your name"`

and it would display "Your name can't be blank"

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue